# Gradient Boosting algorithm for RMLSE(Root mean squared logarithmic error)

Tags: loss-functions, boosting

When the evaluation metric is RMLSE(Root mean squared logarithmic error)
are there any specific advantages of running gradient boosting with RMLSE(Root mean squared logarithmic error) as the loss function over gradient boosting with RMSE as the loss function?